# Concurrently parsing a very large XML file using Stax in Java

Tags: java, xml, concurrency, stax

I need to search and extract a subset of a very large XML file based on a certain key. On very large files (~20 GB), because the stax algorithm I am using searches the document linearly, it takes 7 minutes if the subset is at the end of the file. I am new to Java and concurrency, so my question might be naive and not very clear. So, is it possible to run the same search method on multiple threads such that the first start at the beginning of the XML document, the second one after at 100,000th byte, the 3rd one at the 200,000th byte.. etc.? I am using the  **FileInputStream** in addition to the Stax parsing method. I've read that there is a **FileInputStream.skip()** method which allows one to start reading a file at a certain byte location.

---

Basically, I want to run the same processes on chunks of the document in parallel. Is this possible and a good optimization or I just don't what I'm doing/saying?

Comment: Most (all ?) XML parsers won't allow you to parse incomplete XML files as would happen if you start parsing somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I am not technically parsing the whole thing.. I am just looking for a valid subset within it.. Stax read events and will ignore invalid parts. It reads the file as a stream.. So even if the ending tag is missing it will still return a valid subset of the document.

Comment: You can try to implement Producer - Consumer Pattern

Comment: @amaazouzi Consider cases like CDATA sections or comments (which may contain XML snippets) and you start parsing in the middle of them.

Comment: The problem you have is that you don't know the significance of the 100,000th byte unless you read all the ones before. You could parse the file one and build an index of the location of points to search or even an index of the keys you are looking for. This could be make parallel or even O(1)

Comment: It might be possible if you're prepared to tolerate a small chance of error, e.g. if you happen to start parsing inside a CDATA section or comment. I think you should be able to achieve a little better than 3Gb/minute in raw parsing speed; it's possible that your application logic (what you do with the data delivered by the parser) is slowing it down. But if I were doing this project I would want to explore other possibilities: I don't think the route you are suggesting looks all that promising.

Comment: @MichaelKay The goal is to process such large documents in a couple of seconds. I am not sure if the single-threaded process might improve the situation significantly.. Anyways, I am experimenting with it and I'll see what happens.

Comment: Forget it, there is no way you can process such a large document in a couple of seconds. You need a completely different approach to your system design.

Comment: @MichaelKay--you can't say there is no way. Theoretical one can exploit the fact that time dilates when traveling near the speed of light... so he could leave the machine on earth and take a space trip in a fast rocket, since for his frame of reference a clock ticks slower, there is possibility that when he comes back,and job is done but only 2 seks elapses on his clock...